# how to get index from forEachFeature

Tags: openlayers-3

map._clusterLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {

//how to get index feature?

console.log(featureIndex);

}

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: I have layer which I have been create contain cluster of feature.. I want get all source from map._clusterLayer. so I use that code : 



map._clusterLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {

//how to get index feature?

console.log(featureIndex);

}

that feature is the feature which in map._clusterLayer, now I want get the index of feature..how to get the index that explain feature index

Comment: Better update your question

Comment: hmmm....the conclusion from my question how to get index key from looping in map._clusterLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature)   ...I think it is clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `getId()` function for features:

```
map._clusterLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
  // you may want to set the index depending on other attributes first:
  // feature.setId(feature.get('yourPreferedKeyForIndex'));      
  // get feature index
  var featureIndex = feature.getId();
  console.log(featureIndex);
});
```